# Wordpress dynamic Options Page from arrays and actually save?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to create a plugin to save custom values to `options.php`.

I want to create the fields in arrays and that works.

Where I get lost is this:

1. The form will not actually save the settings in the WP database.
2. How do I create additional sections?

I know it has to do with `add_settings_section()`, etc. But I cannot find how to do this with arrayed inputs. Please advice. ;-)

My code so far:

```
<?php
// Create WordPress admin menu
function stonehenge_menu_page(){
    $page_title = 'Stonehenge Options'; 
    $menu_title = 'Stonehenge Options';
    $capability = 'manage_options';
    $menu_slug  = 'stonehenge_slug';
    $function   = 'stonehenge_render_page';
    $icon_url   = 'dashicons-admin-plugins';
    $position   = 99;

add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );

// Call update_stonehenge function to update database
add_action( 'admin_init', 'update_stonehenge' );
}

// Create function to register plugin settings in the database
function update_stonehenge() {
   register_setting( 'stonehenge-settings', 'stonehenge' );
}

function stonehenge_render_page() {

$section_1 = array(
    'Field 1' => array(             // $name    Name of the field
        'field' => 'field_1',       // $field   
        'label' => 'Field 1',       // $label   Label of the field
        'type' => 'text',           // $type    input type (text, textarea, option, etc.)       
    ),  
    'Field 2' => array(             // $field   Name of the field
        'field' => 'field_2',       // $field
        'label' => 'Field 2',       // $label   Label of the field
        'type' => 'text',           // $type    input type (text, textarea, option, etc.)       
    ),  
    'Field 3' => array(             // $field   Name of the field
        'field' => 'field_3',           // $field
        'label' => 'Field 3',       // $label   Label of the field
        'type' => 'text',           // $type    input type (text, textarea, option, etc.)       
    ),  
);

## START OF MAIN PAGE
echo '<h1>Stonehenge Options Fields</h1>';
?>  
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields( 'stonehenge-settings' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'stonehenge-settings' ); ?>

<!-- >## SECTION 1 should start here </!-->
<br><h2>Section 1</h2>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($section_1 as $var)    {
$prefix         = 'stonehenge_';            
$option_label   = $var['label'];
$option_name    = $var['field'];
$option_field   = 'stonehenge_'.$var['field'];
$option_value   = get_option( $option_field);
$option_input   = '<input type="' .$var['type']. '"name="'.$option_field.'" id="'.$option_field.'" value="'.$option_value.'"> ';
$label_for      = '<label for='.$field.'>' . $var['label'] . '</label>';
?>
    <tr><th scope="row" align="left"><?php echo $option_label; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $option_input; ?></td>
        <td>Database Field = <?php echo $option_field; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<!-- >## SECTION 2 should start here </!-->
<br><h2>Section 2</h2>
<table> 
</table>

<?php submit_button(); ?>
</form> 
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!**

Turns out it was rather simple, if done correctly. :-) Now I can just add an array and **all the rest** is created dynamically. Whoop! Whoop!

Inputs are stored in options.php as stonehenge_section_fieldname and cal be easily called with get_option('stonehenge_section_fieldname');

Here's the code so far, if anyone is interested.

```
// Define common constants for stabiliy.
if (!defined("STONEHENGE_PLUGIN_VERSION"))      define("STONEHENGE_PLUGIN_VERSION", "2.0.0");
if (!defined("STONEHENGE_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH"))     define("STONEHENGE_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH", plugins_url('' , __FILE__));

// TO DO: Add MultiSite compatibility for network Activation.
// Current version only works if activated per blog.

// Let's load the language files.
load_plugin_textdomain('stonehenge', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );

Class Stonehenge_Fields {
    // Add additional Arrays to dynamically create more inputs. That's it!
    static $stonehenge_fields = array(
        'Facebook' => array(            
            'Page URL'  => 'text',                  
            'App ID'    => 'text',      
            'Admin ID'  => 'text',              
        ),  
/*      'Section' => array(         
            'Field 1'   => 'text',                  
            'Field 2'   => 'textarea',      
            'Field 3'   => 'checkbox',              
        ),  
*/
    );

}

// TO DO: Add a hook to remove all option fields upon deactivation of the Plugin.
//delete_option('stonehenge_website_name');


// Call stonehenge_menu function to load Admin Menu in the Dashboard.
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'stonehenge_menu_page' );

// Let's create WordPress Admin Menu
function stonehenge_menu_page(){
  $page_title = __('Stonehenge Custom Fields & Data Settings', 'stonehenge'); 
  $menu_title = __('Stonehenge Fields', 'stonehenge');
  $capability = 'manage_options';
  $menu_slug  = 'stonehenge';
  $function   = 'stonehenge_options_page';
  $icon_url   = 'dashicons-admin-plugins';
  $position   = 99;
  add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
}

function stonehenge_register_settings() {
// Let's create and register the Sections.
   $sections = Stonehenge_Fields::$stonehenge_fields;
    foreach ($sections as $section => $key) {
        add_settings_section($section, $section, 'stonehenge_callback', __FILE__ );

// Let's create and register the input fields in options.php (acutal input fields are created in function stonehenge_options_page. )
        foreach ($key as $name => $type)    {
            $prefix     = 'stonehenge';         
            $field      = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower( $prefix.'_'.$section.'_'.$name ) );
            $label      = ucfirst($section.' '.$name);
            $value      = get_option($prefix.'_'.$section.'_'.$name);
            $input      = '<input type="' .$type. '"name="'.$field.'" id="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'"> ';
            $label_for      = '<label for='.$field.'>' . $label . '</label>';
            add_option($field, $value);
            register_setting('stonehenge_options_group',$field, 'stonehenge_callback');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'stonehenge_register_settings' );

// Let's create the Main Page.
function stonehenge_options_page()
{
?>
  <div class="wrap">
  <h1><?php _e('Stonehenge Custom Fields & Data Settings', 'stonehenge'); ?></h1>
  <form method="post" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields( 'stonehenge_options_group' ); ?>
  <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding"3">

  <?php
//Let's create the Sections
    $sections = Stonehenge_Fields::$stonehenge_fields;
    foreach ($sections as $section => $key) {
        $section_label = ucfirst($section);
        echo ('<th scope="row" colspan="2" align="left"><br><h2>'.$section_label.' '.__('Settings','stonehenge').'</h2></th>');

// Let's create the actual Labels and input Fields 
        foreach ($key as $name => $type)    {
            $prefix     = 'stonehenge';         
            $field      = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower( $prefix.'_'.$section.'_'.$name ) );
            $label      = ucfirst($section.' '.$name);
            $value      = get_option($field);
// TO DO: Create switch arguments for different input types, such as Checkbox, Radio, Textarea, Password, etc.
            $input      = '<input type="' .$type. '"name="'.$field.'" id="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'"> ';
// Using <label for> Makes it clickable. Very handy!
            $label_for      = '<label for='.$field.'>' . $label . '</label>';
            ?><tr><th scope="row" align="left"><?php echo $label_for; ?></th><td><?php echo $input; ?></td></tr><?php 
        }
    }?>
  </table>
  <?php  submit_button(); ?>
  </form>
  </div>
<?php
}

// That's all Folks! :-)

?>
```